# How to keep query parameters in angular 5 on all routes by default?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

#### Background:

The user calls the app's url with the parameters and uses my app. While switching between different routes the url parameters should be kept visible in the browser's address bar.

---

I have to keep the query parameters on each route of my app. That means if I have the url

`www.example.com/app/test?id=326748798342&state=1`

and call a link with `[routerLink]="['/login']"` I have to get this url:

`www.example.com/app/login?id=326748798342&state=1`.

On default I get the login route without the parameters. I found one solution that says to set `queryParamsHandling='merge'`. But this is a very bad solution because that would mean to change all links in templates and all navigate() calls.

Is there a cleaner way to solve this problem on default? Something such setting queryParamsHandling in the routes array for the app or something else?

Comment: Are you passing the `id` and `state` query params to an api or another component?

Comment: In this example "test" and "login" are both components that should be able to read the query parameters. I'm not passing the params to an api.

Comment: I'm not confident I really understand what the problem is. But, I think you could just put `Id` and `state` into `localstorage`, a `Service` or `ngrx Store` and retrieve it to be used in your components without even adding to Url.

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion doesn't solve my problem. The user calls my app's url with the parameters and uses my app. While switching between different routes the url parameters should keep visible in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 18):

Currently there is no way to set it globally. Using `queryParamsHandling` seems to be the only option:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/login']" queryParamsHandling="preserve"></a>
```

Or when using router:

```
router.navigate('/login', { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" })
```

The other possible option for `queryParamsHandling` is `merge`.

Comment: that is something I already wrote in my post above. I want to set this globally.

Comment: @geronimo678, I understand, I just wanted to answer that there's no way to set it globally at the moment and passing `queryParamsHandling` either through `routerLink` or `navigate` is the only option now. Of course, you could implement your own variant of `routerLink` or decorate `Router` but that doesn't seem like a good approach

Comment: I appreciate your help. It seems that I have to use this only solution.
Perhaps there is some better solution in the future...

Comment: @geronimo678, I'll update the answer and let you know if I come across one

Comment: I would solve issue by creating a service which generates url for routerLink. e.g. routerLink=urlService.getLink(['login']) that service function would than handle the merging, preserving and/or removal of url query params