# Angular preserve queryParam on all routes

Tags: angular

I know there is an option to preserve a query param if the navigation is happening directly with routerLink or router. navigate method (through  {queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'}) but I need the following: When the queryParam is set, I want to use it throughout the entire application.
Is it possible to achieve it?

I have a webpage with a specific router configuration:

```html
  {path: 'transport', component: TransportComponent},
  {path: 'events/:id', component: EventsComponent},
  {path: 'pages/:page', component: PagesComponent}
```

This is just a part of it, let's say regular routes.

My problem is that these links can be opened in 2 ways:

1. They can be opened without a location in which case it would be localhost:4200/transport
2. They can be opened with the location in which case it would be localhost:4200/transport?locationName

Location can be selected on home page.

So my idea was to save the location name in queryParam but I struggle to find a way to preserve on every route change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep query parameters in angular 5 on all routes by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995412/how-to-keep-query-parameters-in-angular-5-on-all-routes-by-default)

Comment: Can you explain the use case for your requirement? Maybe there is a better way to preserve that state.

Comment: @VedranMaric Not really, this just preserves the params on direct routing as I explained in my post

Comment: @Silvermind I updated the post with the specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive discussion about this here: [Angular: configure default QueryParamsHandling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988093/angular-configure-default-queryparamshandling)

There's a directive that's applied to the `a[routerLink]` selector. The problem that surfaced was that if you `extend` the `routerLinkDirective`, the `routerLink`s inside a `routerOutlet` seem to have the correct url, but after clicking the link, the queryparams are lost.

The solution was to inject the `routerLinkDirective` rather than extending it

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[routerLink]'
})
export class QueryParamsHandlingDirective {
  constructor (routerLink: RouterLinkWithHref) {
    routerLink.queryParamsHandling = 'merge';
  }
}
```

Credits to @Andrei Gătej

Comment: Looks good, I will try it. Thank you for the answer

Comment: The only limitation here (by angular) is that you cannot specify which queryparams should be preserved and which should be dropped when routerlinks are generated